# android web view in tab layout with fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-webview

I have implemented a tab layout with fragments, and everything works well.
The only thing I don't like is a web view in a tab (which loads every time the same site)
which loads the site every time I go away from the tab and then come back to it.
Is there any way to get the web view to load just once?
I really don't know where to start from...

Here is the code for class TabInfo (helper class) , the add tab method called for all tabs the first time, and the tab change event handler

```
    private class TabInfo {
            private String tag;
            private Class clss;
            private Bundle args;
            private Fragment fragment;

            TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
                this.tag = tag;
                this.clss = clazz;
                this.args = args;
            }

        }

private void addTab(String tag, String title, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        TabSpec ts = getTabSpec(tag, title);
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
        ts.setContent(new TabFactory(this));
        // String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        tabInfo.fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        mTabHost.addTab(ts);
    }


    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {

            try {
                TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
                if (mLastTab != newTab) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (mLastTab != null) {

                        if (mLastTab.fragment != null ) {
                            ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newTab != null) {

                        if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                            newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                            ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                        } else {
                            ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                        }

                    }

                    mLastTab = newTab;
                    ft.commit();
                    // this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                }
                // fillCommonData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogError("error in onTabChanged function", e);
            }
        }
```

thanks

Comment: show your code pls. Just my thoughts, I suppose you use fragments and action bar for tabs. Right? if not you can do not read more... In code you every time call replace fragment and pass new Fragment instance, this way onCreateView and onActivityCreated calls every time and I suppose your webView.loadUrl inside one of this methods, that's why your webview reaload every time. In tabClickListener where you call fragment transaction, you should try find fragment by tag and if fragment exists pass it to transaction with tag, if not-create it

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but override shouldOverrideUrlLoading() and return true when you don't want to reload.

shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is a method of WebViewClient
On your webview, call setWebViewClient and pass it a custom class that implements shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url ){
        if(/* code to determine if already loaded/tab selected */) return true;
        return false;
    }

});
```